# How to create gradle.properties for Module when using Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio will create a Project's gradle.properties by default.
When I add a Module, how do I create a dedicated gradle.properties file for this Module?

I create the gradle.properties manually, but Android Studio doesn't recognize it.

Comment: why you're creating custom gradle.properties? if default already exist

Comment: I want to publish Android library to Maven, so I need to declare some information in gradle.properties, but I don't want to declare it in project's gradle.properties, but module specific.